# solve with Laplace $y''-2y'+2y=0$ detect my mistakes

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

$y''-2y'+2y=0$ and $y(0)=2,y'(0)=0$.
My try:
Ly will be the Laplace function of y.

$\begin{array}{c}
y''-2y'+2y=0\\
y(0)=2,y'(0)=0\\
Ly''=sLy'\\
Ly'=sLy-2\\
Ly''=s(sLy-2)=s^{2}Ly-2s\\
s^{2}Ly-2s-2(sLy-2)+2Ly=0\\
s^{2}Ly-2(sLy)+2Ly=2s-4\\
Ly(s^{2}-2s+2)=2s-4\\
Ly=\frac{2s-4}{(s^{2}-2s+2)}\\
Ly=\frac{2s-4}{(s-1)^{2}+1^{2}}\\
Ly=2\frac{1}{(s-1)^{2}+1^{2}}s-4\frac{1}{(s-1)^{2}+1^{2}}\\
y=-2(e^{t}\sin t)'-4(e^{t}sint)=-4 e^t sin(t) + 2 e^t (cos(t) + sin(t))
\end{array}$

which of course is incorrect.

Comment: just a second this is the correct answer isn't it? @RobertZ

Comment: @LutzLehmann sorry, can you copy the formula?

Comment: I inserted that into my answer. Where did the sign in the first term come from?

Comment: @LutzLehmann you take the derivative and multiply by (-1).

Comment: That you have mixed up with distributions or adjoint operators or something. In your third and fourth line you have it different and correct.

Comment: @LutzLehmann this is what written here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems
I don't understand why it's wrong

Comment: Or you remembered $L\{ty(t)\}(s)=-L\{y(t)\}'(s)$. But here you only used and have to use $$L\{y'(t)\}(s)=sL\{y(t)\}(s)-y(0),$$ forwards and backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y=-2(e^{t}\sin t)'$$
$$y=-2(e^t\sin t +e^t \cos t)$$
Take the Laplace transform :
$$Ly=-2\left(\frac{1}{(s-1)^{2}+1^{2}}+\frac{s-1}{(s-1)^{2}+1^{2}}\right)$$
$$Ly=-\frac{2s}{(s-1)^{2}+1^{2}}$$
There is a sign mistake. You had this :
$$Ly= \color {red}{2\frac{1}{(s-1)^{2}+1^{2}}s}-4\frac{1}{(s-1)^{2}+1^{2}}$$
So that you should have:
$$y=\color {red}{+2}(e^{t}\sin t)'-4(e^{t}\sin t)$$
This agrees with @Lutz Lehmann 's answer.
$$y=2e^t\cos t-2e^t\sin t$$

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the shift to all occurrences of $s$ in
$$
L\{y\}=\frac{2s-4}{(s-1)^{2}+1^{2}}
=\frac{2(s-1)-2}{(s-1)^{2}+1^{2}}
=2L\{\cos t\}(s-1)-2L\{\sin t\}(s-1)
$$
so that
$$
y=2e^t\cos t-2e^t\sin t
$$

Your approach is also correct, if done correctly to the end,
\begin{align}
L\{y\}(s)&=2sL\{\sin t\}(s-1)-4L\{\sin t\}(s-1)\\
&=2L\{(e^t\sin t)'\}-4L\{e^t\sin t\}
\\[1em]\hline
y(t)&=2(e^t\sin t)'-4e^t\sin t\\
&=2e^t\cos t-2e^t\sin t
\end{align}

---

Testing without Laplace
$$
(e^{-t}y)''+e^{-t}y=0, ~~ (e^{-t}y(t))'|_{t=0}=y'(0)-y(0)=-2
\\
\implies
e^{-t}y=2\cos t - 2\sin t
$$
You had the signs right, my memory of the Laplace relations is incomplete. Corrected thanks @Aryadeva

Comment: why the usage of linearity is incorrect?

Comment: I bypassed it didn't I?

Comment: Because $$L\{e^{at}y(t)\}(s)=\int_0^\infty e^{-st}e^{at}y(t)\,dt=L\{y(t)\}(s-a).$$ So $$L\{e^t\cos t\}=L\{\cos t\}(s-1)=\frac{s-1}{(s-1)^2+1}.$$

Comment: why it's incorrect? I used the derivative rule.